# How to fix CSS wide layout issue?

Tags: css, layout

I have layout with default width of 987px and aligned centered and currently working on wide layout feature of site. CSS layout structure is as follows:

```
<div id="BodyContainer">
    <div class="headerouter">
        <div class="outercontainer">
            <uc:Header ID="header1" runat="server" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outercontainer">                
        <div class="main container">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CPM" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='footer'></div>
```

and as if someone chooses a wide layout like having more than 3 columns of record like 4, 5, 6 or 7, then in server side the CSS is overwritten by calculating i.e.

```
outercontainer = no. of columns * 330px;
container = no. of columns * 330px;
```

and in reaction to it outercontainer widths increases but the BodyContainer and footer remains the same and layout breaks. And help or solution to this problem but in CSS only.

CSS are as follows:

```
body {

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
    color: #444;
    background:url('/images/container-back.png') repeat;

    /*Opera Fix*/
    &:before {
        content:"";
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        width:0;
        margin-top:-32767px;
    }
}


html, form { height: 100%; }

#BodyContainer {
    overflow:visible;
    /*padding-bottom: 130px;*/
    min-height:100%; 
    display:block;  
}

.outercontainer {
    width: 987px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 5px 0px 80px 0px;
    position: relative;  
    display:block;

    &:after {
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}

.container {
    width: 987px;
    /*width: 1330px;*/
}
```

check out the problem at the

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/safranali/TzAsq/)

Comment: It would be best to have a live link or seeing it reproduced in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) - that way we could see first-hand what is going on.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts yup doing that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Answer**

Ok - it appears that you are muddling your `.outercontainer` a bit in the HTML. If I remove the additional `.outercontainer` divs and add the class to `#BodyContainer` instead, then this seems to resolve the issue:

```
<div id="BodyContainer" class="outercontainer">
    <div class="headerouter">
        <uc:Header ID="header1" runat="server" /> 
    </div>            
    <div class="main container">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CPM" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='footer'></div>
```

Any styling that was in `.outercontainer` that was being applied to the floating divs can be added to a different CSS class such as `.main`.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TzAsq/9/**

Comment: check out the fiddle and I am also updating the .container with the same formula ...

Comment: @SafranAli The `.outercontainer` is empty in your JSFiddle. What is supposed to be in there? Can you get the JSFiddle to reproduce the bug?

Comment: yup updated the fiddle, in fiddle see the top header as it is not equal to width of the frame

Comment: problem is solved if width is greater like 1640px [if viewing it on 1920*900], but check the out in fiddle by expanding the Result window when outercontainer and container are set to 1315px ...

Comment: Do you mean the large spacing on the right? Also, in your CSS you seem to be nesting classes inside classes - is this for LESS CSS. If I move them out into a normal CSS flow then the page appears to show properly (or at least how I am expecting it to display): http://jsfiddle.net/TzAsq/23/

Comment: yup i know, i tried it ... check it here, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19245786/Capture.PNG

Comment: Ok, on `.outercontainer` I have added a `min-width` which is the width that you are setting dynamically and set `width` to `100%`. I have also changed `width` of `.container` to `100%`. Does that fix the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/TzAsq/25